# How to set max and min value in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="input-group-icon">Max <span class="error">*</span>
<div class="input-group">
    <!--<input style="border-right:none;" name="available_funds_max" ng-model="attributes.available_funds_max"  max="{{constants.globalValue.availablemaxNumber}}" min="{{attributes.available_funds_min}}" type="number" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/" step="0.01" required class="form-control input-sm m-bot15" />--> 
    <input style="border-right:none;" name="available_funds_max" ng-model="attributes.available_funds_max"  ng-maxlength="15"  ng-minlength="1"  type="text" required  class="form-control input-sm m-bot15"  format="number" ng-max="{{constants.globalValue.availablemaxNumber}}" ng-min="{{attributes.available_funds_min}}"/> 
    <span style="border-left:none; background:none; border-color:#e2e2e4; border-radius:0;" class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">{{programname.country.currency_symbol?programname.country.currency_symbol:'$'}}</span> </div>
    <label for="available_funds_max" ng-show="submittab1 && attributesForm.available_funds_max.$error.required" class="error">{{formValidation.required}}</label> 
    <label for="available_funds_max" ng-show="submittab1 && attributesForm.available_funds_max.$error.min" class="error"> {{formValidation.minMax}} </label>
    <label for="available_funds_max" ng-show="submittab1 && attributesForm.available_funds_max.$error.max" class="error"> {{formValidation.anumberMin}} </label>
    <label for="available_funds_max" ng-show="submittab1 && attributesForm.available_funds_max.$error.number" class="error"> {{formValidation.errorNumber}} </label>
    <label for="available_funds_max" ng-show="submittab1 && attributesForm.available_funds_max.$error.maxlength" class="error">Max value too long</label>
    <label for="available_funds_max" ng-show="submittab1 && attributesForm.available_funds_max.$error.minlength" class="error">Max value too short</label>
    <label for="available_funds_max" ng-show="submittab1 && attributesForm.available_funds_min.$error.lowerThan" class="error">Value must be greater than min value</label>
</div>
```

I have set the `max` and `min` value in the `<input type="text" />`. How can I display a validation error when the max or min value has been entered?

I would like to validate the field with the `min` and `max` values, because I don't want to allow numbers in the billions, but only up to a certain maximum. How can I validate the input field and display a validation error message?

Comment: You can't just use "min" and "max" on "text" input. Use "number" input.

Comment: Here is the documentation with error messages: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D

Comment: But i want to check with min and max value in type="text" because am showing no in bilion number like 10,000,how to check When user enter greater than Max value and Min value show error validation?

Comment: @GeethaJanarthanan, take a look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183075/how-to-set-max-and-min-value-in-angular-js/38185265#38185265

Answer (score 7):

Here's a snippet working, just using [`ngMessages`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages):

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', ['ngMessages'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.min = 5;
      $scope.max = 99;
    });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.6.6/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form name="form">
    <label for="input">Input field:</label>
    <input type="number" name="input" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" ng-model="input" required step="0.01" />
    <div ng-messages="form.input.$error" style="color: #ff0000" role="alert" ng-if="form.input.$dirty">
      <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
      <div ng-message="min">This field must be at least {{min}}.</div>
      <div ng-message="max">This field must be at max {{max}}.</div>
      <div ng-message="number">Not a valid number.</div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the max and min value on a text input you can use ng-minlength and ng-maxlength.
Wrap your inputs inside a form and call the $valid on the forms input values to see if the inputs are valid.

It can be used like this:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <label>
       User name:
       <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="name" required ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="4">
    </label>
    <div role="alert">
      <span class="error" ng-show="!myForm.userName.$valid">
       Required!</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

The span will only show when the input with name userName is invalid.
[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/eEEN7HBrMZt7BoYNGGte?p=preview)'s a plunker

Comment: Am set max and min value in text box ? 
is there any option to set min and max value type="text" in angular js?

Comment: @GeethaJanarthanan Am set max and min value in text box ? What do you mean here? If you have a input of type="text" you can use ng-minlength and ng-maxlength, That's a angularjs way of setting it. You can use ng-minlength and ng-maxlength on more type of inputs as well.

Comment: i want to Check value in textbox , suppose in min ="5" max="20,000",so user can't enter max value 20,001 and min 4 value once he enter that value i ll show error message.like type="number" we set min and max value same functionality i want to check in type="text"

Answer (score 1):

> Set min value.  It should be numeric
>
> ```
> <input type="text" ng-model="bundle.quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control text-right" placeholder="" ng-min="1" required>
> ```
>
> If the attribute value is numeric then It will display otherwise it will remove from the DOM and make it form as invalid. Simply It will not allow the invalid values

```
app.directive('ngMin', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.$watch(attr.ngMin, function() {
                ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$viewValue);
            });
            var minValidator = function(value) {
                var min = attr.ngMin || 0;
                if (!isEmpty(value) && value < min) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('ngMin', false);
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('ngMin', true);
                    return value;
                }
            };
            ctrl.$parsers.push(minValidator);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(minValidator);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: A short description on what the code does or how it fixes the actual question would be good.

Comment: now we have validators.  don't have to use parsers and formatters for this.  ctrl.$validators = etc

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Angular `ngMessages` directive. Then you can group up your error messages like this and it's really easy to use:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);
```

```css
div[role="alert"] {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <form name="demoForm">
    <label for="myField">Text field:</label><br>
    <input type="text"
           name="myField"
           ng-model="field"
           ng-minlength="5"
           ng-maxlength="20"
           required />
    <div ng-messages="demoForm.myField.$error" role="alert">
      <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
      <div ng-message="minlength">This field should be at least 5 characters long</div>
      <div ng-message="maxlength">This field should be less than 20 characters long</div>
    </div>
    <label for="myField2">Number field:</label><br>
    <input type="number"
           name="myField2"
           ng-model="field2"
           ng-minlength="5"
           ng-maxlength="20"
           required />
    <div ng-messages="demoForm.myField2.$error" role="alert">
      <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
      <div ng-message="minlength">This field should be at least 5 characters long</div>
      <div ng-message="maxlength">This field should be less than 20 characters long</div>
    </div>
  </form>  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.16/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Official documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages

**EDIT based on comments:**

I think I now understood what it is that you want. Please see the following code snippet for an answer. I made custom directives for the min and max values that you can set and which will validate the input. There is also a pattern check on the input with `ng-pattern` which will allow numbers, commas and dots and show error accordingly (You could modify this to not allow to insert anything else than numbers and commas etc). Please modify this for your needs but I think this is a good starting point for you.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);

app.directive('customMin', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            var minValidator = function (value) {
                var min = scope.$eval(attr.customMin) || 0;
                if (value) {
                 value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                }
                console.log(value);
                if (!isEmpty(value) && value < min) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('customMin', false);
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('customMin', true);
                    return value;
                }
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.push(minValidator);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(minValidator);
        }
    };
});

app.directive('customMax', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            var maxValidator = function (value) {
                var max = scope.$eval(attr.customMax) || Infinity;
                if (value) {
                 value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
                }
                console.log(value);
                if (!isEmpty(value) && value > max) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('customMax', false);
                    return undefined;
                } else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('customMax', true);
                    return value;
                }
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.push(maxValidator);
            ctrl.$formatters.push(maxValidator);
        }
    };
});

function isEmpty(value) {
    return angular.isUndefined(value) || value === '' || value === null || value !== value;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="app">
      <form name="myForm">
        Value:
        <input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-pattern="/[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)*/" custom-min="5" custom-max="20000" name="value" />
        <div ng-messages="myForm.value.$error" role="alert">
          <div ng-message="pattern">There are some characters that are not allowed</div>
          <div ng-message="customMin">This field should be at least value of 5</div>
          <div ng-message="customMax">This field should be at most value 20,000</div>
        </div>
        <br> 
        <tt>value = {{value}}</tt>
        <br>
        <tt>value.$valid = {{myForm.value.$valid}}</tt>
        <br>
        <tt>value.$error = {{myForm.value.$error}}</tt>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a tip: seems the OP wants it as type="number".

Comment: Hmm ok, It's kind of hard to read the question but this solution should work either way. Please let me know if I understood something incorrectly.

Comment: Am Checking value in textbox , suppose in min ="5" max="20,000",so user can't enter max value 20,001 and min 4 value once he enter that value i ll show error message.

Comment: Hi, I made an edit on my answer which might be helpful. Please see the fiddle.

Comment: I modified it again to use ng-messages and made a code snippet of it in the answer. Please see if the edited answer is any use for you.